# Actionscript 3 mouseover passthough (ignore mouse events)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a button with a MovieClip over the top of it. 
Is there an easy way to tell flash to ignore the mouseOver events of the MovieClip
in ActionScript so my button doesn't flash?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the [mouseEnabled](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#mouseEnabled) property.